# Neural network quantization

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, quantization

How do I use pytorch1.12.0 cpuonly to specify the quantization model as float16?

I want to use pytorch 1.12.0 to complete resnet18 quantization both int8 and float16

or if tensorflow is better than pytorch when I need to do quantization

Comment: Please show the code you tried so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.